# Show requests made by ServiceWorker in Firefox DevTools?

Tags: service-worker, firefox-developer-tools

If a ServiceWorker intercepts a web request and manipulates it (e.g. change the status code), in Chrome DevTools both requests are shown - The service worker request with the original status code, and the modified request returned to the code with the changed status code.

In Firefox DevTools only the modified request is shown, so I can't see what the request looked like before the ServiceWorker modified it. How can I achieve thee same behaviour as in Chrome to view the request before it was modified in Firefox DevTools?

Comment: Hello! I've bumped into the same issue today, have you figured a way to do it ?